# SQL:find table1.col1 not exist table2.col2, return table1's records

Tags: sql

This is my statement

```
select * from table1
where col1 not in (select col2 from table2);
```

I want to try(but failed)

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
inner join table2 on t1.col1<> t2.col2
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What's the expected result of the sub-query returns a null? (I.e. if table2 has a col2 value that is null.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col2
where t2.col2 is null
```

This is standard implementation of missing record search.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined `t2` object and use `left join`.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.col2 = t1.col1 WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the records that exists in table1 but does't exists in table2 you need a [`left join`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp), not an [`inner join`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

Try this:

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col2
where t2.id is null -- any non-nullable column will do, best to use pk for performance.
```

Answer (score 0):

If You try to find out the data of t1.c1 (t1=table1, c1=column1) that is exist or not exist in t2.c2 then use flowing script

`select t1.c1 from t1 left join t2 on t1.c1=t2.c2`

other wise if you want to find only t1.c1 data that is not in t2.c2 then below script is help full

`select t1.c1 from t1 where t1.c1 not in (select t2.c2 from t2)`